# Чтените текста из word файла

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли читать текстовый файл word, который содержится в ресурсах приложения ?

Comment: так файл текстовый или ms word?

Comment: из ресурсов читать, конечно, можно - они на то и ресурсы

Comment: Z.John, имел в виду doc файл, который содержит только текст

Comment: doc файл это принципиально, почему выбран именно такой формат?

Comment: Просто текст, который необходимо отображать для пользователя, сознан в doc. И таких файлов очень много

Comment: Тексты большие по объему? с форматированием? Почему не подходит простой файл например message.properties?

Comment: Файл по содержанию короткий без форматирования, только отображение. Но таких файлов около 1000

Comment: Это извращение. Создаете один файл message.properties они для этого и созданы и переносите в него сообщения из всех файлов в формате ключ-значение.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете один файл message.properties они для этого и созданы и переносите в него сообщения из всех файлов в формате ключ-значение. Потом загружаете файл в объект Properties методом load и обращаетесь к нужному вам сообщению по ключу.

p.s. см комментарии к вопросу